Using Latex with two plots next to each other error with subfigure
i am running the following code:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$f$,
                ylabel={$P(f)$},
                ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
                xmin=0, xmax=3.1,
            ]
            \addplot [
                domain=1:2, 
                samples=100, 
                color=red,
            ]
            {1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uniform distribution of a frequency $f$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$t$,
                ylabel={$P(t)$},
                ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
                xmin=0, xmax=3.1, % Provide valid values for xmin and xmax
            ]
            \addplot [
                domain=1:2, % Avoid division by zero by starting slightly above 1
                samples=100, 
                color=red,
            ]
            {1/(x - 1)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Periodic duration of uniform distribution of a frequency $f$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Comparison of uniform distribution and periodic function}
    \label{fig:uniform_vs_periodic}
\end{figure}

The error i get is:
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>LaTeX
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)LaTeX
``


Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

If I insert your code fragment in some working document, it compile without errors, warnings  and bad boxes. So your source of error is outside of of showed code. Please extend it to complete small document, which reproduce showed error.

Any news? Does provided answer solve your problem? If not, pleas clarify your questions as you has been asked in above comments. If yes, consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer)

As I mentioned in my comment, if I extend your code fragment to MWE, obtained MWE not produce errors which you reported in your question. So the source of your trauble is out of showed code.
A possible MWE, which consider a bit shortened version of your code, is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,
             axis lines=left,
             ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
             xmin=0, xmax=3.1,
             samples=100,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, red}
             }
             
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=$f$,
                ylabel={$P(f)$},             
                        ]
            \addplot [domain=1:3]
            {1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uniform distribution of a frequency $f$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=$t$,
                ylabel={$P(t)$},
                        ]
            \addplot [domain=1:4]
            {1/(x - 1)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Periodic duration of uniform distribution of a frequency $f$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Comparison of uniform distribution and periodic function}
    \label{fig:uniform_vs_periodic}
\end{figure}

which produce:

Compilation going smooth: no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes. So you need to:

extend your code fragment to MWE, similar to mine above, which reproduce reported errors.
examine original document if it has in preamble loaded a package, which may cause your problem

